# Xcode 6 beta: Resizable iPhone will not resize

Tags: xcode, xcode6, beta

The word "resizable" suggests that you can, you know, *resize* something. But in the case of the Xcode 6 beta, the "Resizable iPhone" feature just wants to stay at 320x1024. I would have liked to RESIZE the iPhone to the rumored iPhone 6 screen size of 960x1704 so that I can, you know, make software for the iPhone 6 (which is *supposed* to be the reason why the beta is out....). Why is it not resizing?